# Cannot find module './auth/auth.service'

Tags: javascript, angular

I started a blank Angular app and began following Auth0's [setup guide](https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/soundcloud/), opting to use `npm install` in lieu of using yarn or including the script from Auth0's CDN. I don't get past step 1 ("Setup your application's code" in the header) without getting the following errors when I run `ng serve`:

```
 ERROR in /Users/g/Documents/Projects/login/src/app/app.component.ts (2,29): Cannot find module './auth/auth.service'.
 ERROR in /Users/g/Documents/Projects/login/src/app/app.component.ts (10,28): Cannot find name 'Authservice'.
```

Here is my app.component.ts code (the only code I modified from Angular's blank setup):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public auth: Authservice) {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? There isn't a lot of opportunity for error in the first step of that guide, but I'm guessing part of the problem is that running npm install --save auth0-js doesn't put an "auth" folder in my project, and it appears that the second line of code in my app.component.ts file is trying to reference an "auth" folder.

Comment: If you don't have a file named `auth.service.ts` inside a folder called `auth` that is in the same folder as your `app.component.ts` file, then it won't work.

Comment: I think there is one thing missing in the steps for setup.

You gotta import the "auth0-js" module in your app module.

if you have done so already then you can use the authservice like 

import { AuthService } from 'auth0-js';

Comment: So @AmanArora what would that look like? I tried `import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';` but got the same errors.

Comment: Actually, that depends on how auth0-js exports its functionality. Did you try this : import { AuthService } from 'auth0-js'; ??

Comment: @AmanArora I did... that gives me `ERROR in /Users/g/Documents/Projects/login/src/app/app.component.ts (10,28): Cannot find name 'Authservice'.`

Comment: @joevern seems like there is a change in the usage of the package. Added links to the latest usage and documentation in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auth0 support linked me to [this solution](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/soundcloud). I can't implement it because I can't change the callback URI for my project but I'm leaving it here for the record.

Answer (score 1):

@joevern

Seems like you are using a setup guide that is no longer valid. Here's an updated link to the Packages' documentation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth0-js

To get started, All you need to do is `npm install` the `auth0-js` package, and then import it in your component like this.

```
import * as auth0 from "auth0-js";
```

On how to use the variable auth0, you can refer the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own service or you can download and use library like : https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-7-registration-login-example/tree/master/src/app/_services